# Erro ao passar um objeto do Thymeleaf para o controller (post) do Spring Boot

Tags: java, hibernate, aplicação-web, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Tenho esse controller:

```
@PostMapping("/salvar")
public String salvar(@Valid OrdemServico ordemServico, BindingResult result,
                     RedirectAttributes attr) {

    if (result.hasErrors()){
        return "ordemServico/cadastro";
    }

    service.save(ordemServico);
    attr.addFlashAttribute("success", "Ordem de Servico inserido com sucesso");
    return "redirect:/os/cadastrar";

}
```

no template do thymeleaf:

```
<form th:action="@{/os/salvar}"
                  th:object="${ordemServico}" method="POST">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="cliente">Cliente</label>
                        <select id="cliente" class="form-control" th:field="*{cliente}"
                                th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('cliente')} ? 'is-invalid'">
                            <option value="">Selecione...</option>
                            <option th:each="cliente : ${clientes}" th:value="${cliente}"
                                    th:text="${cliente.nome}">Cliente</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            <span th:errors="*{cliente}"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

O objetivo é cadastrar uma ordem de servico,que se relaciona com um Cliente(entidade tbm)

```
public class OrdemServico{


@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="seq_id", strategy="com.web.mja.mja.domain.CodigoOSGenerator")
@GeneratedValue(generator="seq_id")
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
private String codigo;

@Column
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dataEntrada;

@Column
@UpdateTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dataAtualizacao;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cliente_id_fk")
private Cliente cliente;

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private TipoEquipamento tipo;

@NotNull
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Marca marca;
```

Mas ao escolher um cliente no template, preencher outros campos e mandar o request. Ele dá erro de conversao. VAi uma String ao invés do objeto cliente escolhido.

erro:
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type com.web.mja.mja.domain.Cliente for property cliente; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type java.lang.String to required type com.web.mja.mja.domain.Cliente for property cliente: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Answer (score 1):

```
<option th:each="cliente : ${clientes}" th:value="${cliente}"
                                    th:text="${cliente.nome}">Cliente</option>
```

neste ponto você está setando o th:value com o objeto cliente, porém, o thymeleaf converte este valor para uma String (o campo value não aceita objeto), ou seja, o value está sendo igual ao endereço de memória do objeto cliente.

Exemplo:
`com.web.mja.mja.domain.Cliente@2b93571c`

o valor do seu option é mais ou menos este exemplo acima.

Visto que você não vai ter um objeto cliente na página, você poderia trocar o atributo cliente para string ou Long e fazer este relacionamento apenas no banco de dados.

Exemplo: na coluna cliente da ordem de serviço seria apenas o ID ou o Código/Nome do cliente, no banco de dados esta coluna seria uma Foreign key da tabela cliente. e o option ficaria assim:

```
<option th:each="cliente : ${clientes}" th:value="${cliente.id}"
                                    th:text="${cliente.nome}">Cliente</option>
```

Esta é uma opção que contornaria este problema.

Outra opção é criar uma classe OrdemServicoDAO com o atributo String cliente, no controller você receberia OrdemServicoDAO e não OrdemServico, em seguida você manda para a camada de serviço e lá você converteria OrdemServicoDAO para OrdemServico.

Exemplo:

```
@PostMapping("/salvar")
public String salvar(@Valid OrdemServicoDAO ordemServicoDAO, BindingResult result,
                     RedirectAttributes attr) {

    if (result.hasErrors()){
        return "ordemServico/cadastro";
    }

    service.save(ordemServicoDAO);
    attr.addFlashAttribute("success", "Ordem de Servico inserido com sucesso");
    return "redirect:/os/cadastrar";

}
```

no método save basta criar um objeto OrdemServico e passar os valores de ordemServicoDAO para ele, no campo cliente você busca o cliente no banco de dados através da String cliente do ordemServicoDAO e atribui o ao atributo da OrdemServico.
exemplo:

```
ordemServico.setCliente(clienteRepository.findById(ordemServicoDAO.getCliente()));
```